# Not interrupt, but pause PostgreSQL indexing process

Tags: postgresql, indexing

Started migration to PG13 -> PG14. After pouring the dump, started rebuilding the index.
The problem is that I must not have adjusted all the settings because the process went too slow.
Is it possible not to stop it, but suspend it? To tweak the settings (to make them the same as in version 13 were) and then continue indexing, and not start from scratch?

And by the way, what settings are most important when building indexes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you'd have to restart the process if you interrupt it.

Set `maintenance_work_mem` high, and for recent versions, set `max_parallel_maintenance_workers` as high as you can afford.